# How to read appsettings.json in xunit test project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit.net

I am trying to write the test cases for one of the method written in MVC controller and in that method I am reading AppSettings.json file. as below

```
public class MemberController : ControllerBase
{
    IMemberRepository _memberRepository;
    public PayPalKeys payPal;
    public ActiveDirectory activeDirectory;
    private static GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    public MemberController(IMemberRepository member, IOptions<PayPalKeys> payPal, IOptions<ActiveDirectory> activeDirectory)
    {
        _memberRepository = member;
        this.payPal = payPal.Value;
        this.activeDirectory = activeDirectory.Value;
    }   
    
    private IConfigurationRoot LoadAppSettings()
    {
        try {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .Build();
            -
            -
            -
        }
        catch(Exception ae){}
    }
}
```

and the below is my Test code

```
[Fact]
public void Payment()
{
    var memberRepositoryManagerMock = new Mock<IMemberRepository>();     
    var members = new Members() {};
    var controller = new MemberController(memberRepositoryManagerMock.Object, GetPayPalConfigurationMock().Object, GetActiveDirectoryConfigurationMock().Object);
    var result = controller.MakePayment(members);
}
```

and that method from controller gives the exception as

> The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'F:\API.Test\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\appsettings.json'.

Here I am not understanding that how to mock that "appsettings.json" part in the test case code.

Comment: Is the method your attempting to test calling `LoadAppSettings`? Because that should really only be called on the start up of the application and not as part of controllers... you are already injecting `IOptions<T>` so why do you need to rebuild the `IConfiguration` in the controller?

Comment: Have you included a line in your csproj (for the test project) to pull the appsettings.json across from your (I'm assuming) main project? Something like the following would do it: `<None Include="/path/to/your/appsettings.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" /></ItemGroup>`

Comment: @JamieRees am doing that caouse am modifiyng that appseetings.json file though code, yes i am injecting IOptions<T> but that is of other type.

Answer (score 13):

Right click on the settings file in Visual Studio and set the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always" or "Copy when never".

[image]

To be more precise of the file location, change your configuration-builder to do that:

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .Build();
```