# Validate appsettings.json as part of CI/CD pipeline

Tags: .net-core, continuous-integration, appsettings

I have this working as part of `Startup.cs` to validate that there are no missing configuration settings and this works as the app will fail to run if it's missing a setting, but I wondered if this can be added as a step or job as part of the pipeline before deploying to QA/UAT/Prod.

Answer (score 1):

You could include a Unit Test that fails if any of your required configurations are missing.

Assuming you're running the Unit Tests as part of the build pipeline, if the test fails it should prevent deployment.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491717/how-to-read-appsettings-json-in-xunit-test-project) might help you achieve this.

Comment: It's GutHub actions but I believe both create the same template. A unit test to do this will be good. I'll give it a try. Thanks!